# Symfony2 bundles confusion

Tags: symfony

I am following the instructions on [creating a sample application](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html). I am trying to quickly get to grips on how to create a few (for now) static pages - no user authentication, no ORM etc, just to get something up and running.

I have created two bundles:

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=app1/FooBundle --format=yml
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=app2/FooBarBundle --format=yml
```

from the documentation (and knowledge of how Symfony 1.x worked), I expected to be able to access the two 'applications' using:

```
http://sf2.examples.localhost/app_dev.php/app1/hello/angrycoder
http://sf2.examples.localhost/app_dev.php/app2/hello/angrycoder
```

However, in both cases, I simply got a 404 error.

Upon going back to the documentation, I read that the correct URL to use was;

```
http://sf2.examples.localhost/app_dev.php/hello/angrycoder
```

That seems to 'work' in so far as a page with **angrycoder** was displayed.

HOWEVER - I have no idea which application has actually been called - since I haven't yet figured out how to display the debug toolbar.

My question therefore is this:

1. How do I get to a specific page (static or otherwise) in a given bundle?.

**[[Edit]]**

```
This is what my app/config/routing.yml file looks like:

app1CoreBundle:
    resource: "@app1CoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app2CoreBundle:
    resource: "@app2CoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#   resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#   prefix:   /_internal
```

As can be seen, both have a prefix of '/'. So when I type:

```
http://sf2.examples.localhost/app_dev.php/hello/angrycoder
```

Which application is actually called (and why?).

From my understanding, the only (obvious way) to be able to call specific applications - is to use different prefixes for different applications - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the routing system for that kind of needs.
So if you go to `app/config/routing` or, more in detail, into `src/app1/FooBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` you can change the page displayed

In detail

```
// app/config/routing.yml
AcmeHelloBundle
resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
//end

// src/Acme/AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
AcmeHelloBundle_homepage:
pattern:  /hello/{name}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index }
//end
```

In that way, i'am telling to symfony to find che routing system and rules, for `AcmeHelloBundle` into the file `AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` 
After, into `AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` I say that every path that will come with a url like `/hello{placeHolder}` will pass into `Default` controllor and will render `index`.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Actually, I just worked that out a few minutes ago. Thanks for confirming that though.

Comment: Don: Thanks for the detailed explanation. BTW, do you know how I can turn on the web debug toolbar under SF2?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli : i'm just new in symfony as you are :) (studied for two weeks about) so i can't tell you with certainty. But if you downloaded the entire framework, you could access to a page (demo, but i don't remember what) that have this bar. If you take a look to this, maybe you can find some interesting things

Comment: @j0k: Thats what I have in my config_dev.php. However, the toolbar is still not being displayed ..

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli did you check the whole question/answers?

Answer (score 1):

Forget what you know about Symfony 1.x when you're working with Symfony 2.  Besides the name and the overall MVC approach, they are *very* different frameworks.

Symfony 2 doesn't have "apps" the way Symfony 1 does. You can sort of treat your own Bundles like symfony 1 apps, but make no mistake: there is no direct analogue.  Bundles are much more generic and flexible than apps (which is a good thing)

As you're discovering, access to a bundle's controllers is completely governed by the routing system.